# Permissions denied to create folder in caches or library directory

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

Before we start, I feel like I need to say I am using Xcode 8 beta 6!

I am trying to create a folder in my `.cachesDirectory` or `.libraryDirectory` but getting back a "Permission denied" error.

I am getting the path here:

```
static func luiFolderPath() -> String {
    let basePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: basePath).appendingPathComponent("LiveUI")?.absoluteString
    return path!
}
```

And this is how I want to create my folder:

```
static func createFolder(dataPath: String) -> Bool {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch {
        Debugging.report(error: error)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 
"You don’t have permission to save the file “LiveUI” in the folder “Caches”."
UserInfo={
    NSFilePath=file:///Users ... A68D8/Library/Caches/LiveUI,
    NSUnderlyingError=0x60000004bee0 {
        Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"
    }
}
```

Anybody has an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: `absoluteString` is the wrong method to get a file path from the URL, use `path` instead, or work with URLs only.